Movie with robot kid and parents who abandon him
In this movie the kid is a robot that the parents adopt and then abandon. He has blonde hair and also in on of the scenes they go to this abandoned city where most of it is under water. Does anyone remember this movies name?

It's probably Steven Spielberg's A.I. Artificial Intelligence, (2001):

One of the mecha-producing companies builds David, an artificial kid
  which is the first to have real feelings, especially a never-ending
  love for his "mother", Monica. Monica is the woman who adopted him as
  a substitute for her real son, who remains in cryo-stasis, stricken by
  an incurable disease. David is living happily with Monica and her
  husband, but when their real son returns home after a cure is
  discovered, his life changes dramatically.


I'll add that towards the end of the movie, David (the robo-kid played by Haley Joel Osmet) is in a submerged city under the ocean.

AI - Artificial Intelligence.
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0212720/
